# Getting contents of Listbox in MVC 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a view for my customer object that allows him to choose a number of products.

In my view, want to show a list box (products chosen by my customer) and then on the client side add and remove items to it. I then need to pass all the data from the list box back to my action so that I can iterate over the list and save it in the database.

How do I pass the whole list back to the action and what should the parameters for the action?

On the client side I think I can add and remove option tags for the products chosen.

I am aware of model binding but I have no idea how I can bind a listbox to an object structure.

JD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of an advanced solution, but I've found that using [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) for doing list manipulation client-side is much easier than using MVC's built in list support. Steve Sanderson has a great [walk though](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/07/12/editing-a-variable-length-list-knockout-style/) on how to implement this. He also has a [walk though](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/validating-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) using only MVC + forms. I'd suggest working through both. Either of these solutions will be much more maintainable/extensible than posting a comma separated string back to the server.

Comment: Thank you. Just spent the last few hours looking at Knockout and I have managed to get most of the UI done without any messing around with the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to make your method accept a list of strings or integers, like:

```
public ActionResult About(List<string> products);
```

The default model binder will now bind all your products to your list.

You can also make your method accept a FormCollection and split the content of your listbox, like:

```
public ActionResult Products(FormCollection form)
{
    var products = form["Products"].Split(',');
}
```

Products will now contain all your products.

Comment: Hi Alexn,  I am still pretty new to MVC 2 and I have seen examples where html elements have ids like Product[index].Name etc and this gets binded to a .Net collection. The list box has a single id, so not sure what you mean by slitting the content of the list box. Also, any more info on a custom model binder would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, did not know if you saw my edit. If the value of your options is a single id, you're fine with just accepting a `List<int>` in your action method. The default model binder will handle this. What i meant by splitting on `,` is that your browser will send the data in a form like `products=1,2,3`.